# How to open an URL through wsl2?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm connecting to a VPN using openvpn through wsl2 (kali linux). The issue I have is the following: I can't access sites in the network through the browser as wsl2 follows the URLs using the windows API and windows isn't connected to the VPN. How can I access sites in the browser through wsl2?

Detail: What I'm asking for is to connect to a site hosted in a remote server using my desktop browser, but route the connection through WSL as I'm connected to the network where the server is through a VPN using WSL.

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  Don't forget to close out the question on Stack Overflow.  I'm pretty sure it's better for overall rep if you do it rather than wait on one of the mods to find it and close it.  I'll attempt to help answer this one, but I have to say, I don't see it as being easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw out some quick thoughts here to maybe get you started.  I'll come back and hopefully add some detail later.

I don't see this as being easy, but I do *think* it's possible.  I haven't done an openvpn connection from inside WSL, but I think I can visualize the flow.

The hard part is that you are connecting the WSL2 (Hyper-V) virtual NIC to the VPN, so all traffic between WSL2 and the VPN endpoint is encrypted, giving the Windows NIC no way to tap into it (even though it is "hosting" the virtual network).

The good news is that there *is* a way to "tap into" the WSL network from Windows, albeit "hacky".  Again, I'm just going to lay out the basics here of what I believe *might* work.  I'll have to come back with more details later.

`socat` is a networking tool that allows you to redirect network traffic over a number of different link types.  One of these links, interestingly enough, is stdio.  I've successfully connected to WSL2 stdio with socat using the `wsl` command.  (See ["Option 3" in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833)).

My hope is that you could set up a proxy server in a WSL1 instance with a port mapped through stdio to socat running in the WSL2 instance.  The Windows' browser would then connect to the proxy server and be able to tunnel out through the WSL2 VPN.

There's even a `socat` compiled for Windows that would probably simplify this even further, but I haven't tried that yet.

Like I said at the start -- Not exactly easy.

Out of time for the moment.  Do you think this is a path you'd want to take?