# SSH into WSL from another machine on the network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to deploy a distributed systems using Windows machines. However, the code I want to compile and run on this system should get complied in a Linux-based environment. Thus, I downloaded and installed WSL and Ubuntu on all nodes. Now, I need to SSH into the worker nodes from the controller node. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in OpenSSH client?

Comment: You mean installing OpenSSH for all nodes and calling and accessing them from the controller node? Does it work for LAN machines?

Comment: Does what work for lAN machines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### SSH into WSL1

If the WSL instances are WSL1, then you can install SSH on those instances and access them directly.  It sounds like you may have multiple WSL "node" instances on one Windows host, and if that's the case, then you should, of course, have a different port number for each SSH server in its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Note that you'll still need a reliable way to *start* the SSH services on those instances (see below).

#### SSH into WSL2

If you must run WSL2 on the node instances, then you'll need to go a slightly different route, since as you seem to be aware (from your comment on the question), accessing them from the LAN is not straightforward, but there are multiple options to make it work.

To start with, check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833) that I've provided on another similar question, just to understand the issue better.

##### Simplified option for those just needing remote command-line access to WSL

This doesn't sound like it's an option for your original question, but I'm including it here for others that may not need a full-blown ssh solution:

*Note that this requires either a very old version of WSL or the (at this time) absolute latest version 2.0.0 pre-release.*

- First [set up OpenSSH server on the Windows' host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).
- As long as you can directly access the Windows host, you can `ssh` directly into PowerShell on the Windows host.
- Then, from the CMD ssh command-line, you can just run `wsl ~` to get access to your WSL instance remotely.
- This can even be simplified into a one-liner with:

  - (Older WSL releases): `ssh -t <windowshost> "wsl ~"`
  - 2.0.0 and later:  `ssh -t  '"C:\Program Files\WSL\wsl.exe" ~'

    While the WSL development team has mentioned that they want to get back to being able to use just `wsl`, that's not working just yet.  For that reason, the double-quotes are required.  The outer single-quote is for the Bash shell from which I'm calling `ssh`, and the inner double-quotes are for the CMD interpreter which is being called by the Windows OpenSSH.

  If by some outrageous coincidence you are using [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1629407/1210833) to launch OpenSSH with PowerShell with no logo, then the invocation becomes:

  ```
  ssh -t <windowshost> 'C:\Program` Files\WSL\wsl.exe'
  ```

##### Full remote WSL2 ssh support

In your case, it sounds like your controller will need automatic ssh access to the remote WSL2 instances.  That can still be done, but requires a little more effort.  The way that I handle this on my network (for Ansible configuration of those nodes) is to:

- As with the simplified option, [set up OpenSSH server on the Windows' host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).  I use the default port 22 for the "host" ssh, but you don't necessarily have to.
- Next, set up SSH for each WSL instance.  Here, I use a different port number for each instance.
- Optional, but recommended, set up both the Windows OpenSSH and the WSL instances with your public key in `../ssh/authorized_keys` (on Windows OpenSSH, this is under your `%userprofile%/.ssh` directory.  In Linux/WSL, of course, it's in `~/.ssh`.

Now, since each Windows host can access the WSL2 instances on `localhost`, you can use the Windows SSH as a jumphost to the WSL2 SSH sessions.

For instance:

`ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p windowshost.local" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -p 2224 localhost`

This uses the port 22 OpenSSH server running on Windows at "windowshost.local" (insert your name or IP here) to access the WSL instance running on its port 2224.  Note that `localhost` is always going to be `localhost` here, since port 2224 is local to "windowsthost.local".

StrictHostKeyChecking needs to be off in this case, since you are going to have a lot of "localhosts" in your `known_hosts`, and ssh doesn't take into account jumphosts when looking up keys.

Of course, this can be *greatly* simplified with a `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host wsl-ubuntu.windowshost.local
HostName localhost
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p windowshost.local
StrictHostKeyChecking no
Port 2224
```

You can then access the WSL session directly via `ssh wsl-ubuntu.windowshost.local`.  Make the hostname whatever you want in the `config`.

Note that this jumphost technique is only needed for automation which requires "real" SSH into the WSL instance.  If you just need to "access" the WSL instance's terminal remotely, you can shortcut it with:

`ssh -t windowshost.local wsl` or `ssh -t windowshost.local wsl -d Ubuntu20.04`

The first one just launches into the default WSL instance. The second allows you to select a specific instance/distribution by name.  See the path and quoting rules above if using WSL 2.0.0.

##### Starting SSH in WSL

You could get fancy and try to [bring up your WSL nodes and their SSH servers when Windows boots](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723) via Windows Task Scheduler or another means.  But if you use the Windows SSH server technique mentioned above (including for your WSL1 hosts), then you can bring them up on demand via:

`ssh -o "RemoteCommand=wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 sudo service ssh status ^|^| sudo service ssh start" windowshost_ip_or_name`

This logs into the Windows host and uses the `wsl` command to access the WSL instance by name, running the command to check whether SSH is running and start the service if it isn't.  Note that the ^|^| is escaping the || for CMD, since CMD is the default shell when you SSH into a Windows OpenSSH server (although this can be changed).

##### Other options

You can also change your Windows `ssh` default shell to be WSL, so that when you connect to OpenSSH on Windows, it drops you directly into WSL.  I won't repeat the steps here, but see [these Microsoft instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows) and my [related question/answer](https://superuser.com/a/1629407/1210833) on how to extend this to WSL.

Personally, I don't recommend this approach if you ever think you may use more than one WSL instance.  I change my default shell to PowerShell Core, which still allows me easy access to WSL as documented above.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comprehensive answer @NotTheDr01ds. You truly helped me out.

Comment: If you are using OpenSSH and your account is part of local administrators, you'll need to setup public key in a special way see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#administrative-user

Comment: This (_Full remote WSL2 ssh support_) works just great, thank you! Probably even a bit easier is the use of `-J windowshost.local` (or `ProxyJump windowshost.local` in the configuration), which at least also works in my scenario. ;-)

Comment: is this still so complicated to ssh into WSL2 from the Windows Host in 2024?

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, forward your port from the public IP port to the WSL port in powershell as admin using:

*netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$EXT_PORT listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=$WSL_PORT connectaddress=127.0.0.1*

To forward SSH access to WSL, $EXT_PORT=2222, $WSL_PORT=22
After above set up, from another computer in same LAN or VPN, do

*ssh user@wslhostip -p 2222*

Advantage of this approach is that no extra set up in WSL other than setting up SSH service as in any Linux distribution. It's also a generic way for setting up other networking service by just changing the forwarding ports.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution, using VSCode Remote Server don't allow to jump or any specific command

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the post, but here is a useful answer that uses Remote -- Tunnels extension.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389647

> It appears that, for now, you need to manually install the CLI in WSL in order for it to work. The downloads can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads). Since you are on Windows, I would recommend the x64 CLI download. When you extract the `tar.gz` file, you will get a file named code. I would recommend moving it to your home directory for ease. To open the tunnel, run `./code tunnel` (from wherever you put the `code` file) to force the new CLI. If you use `code tunnel` it will still use the Windows version.
>
> Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171196

Comment: That seems to be a *really* different issue than what is being asked in this question.  VSCode tunnels are for running VSCode on a remote system, not a generic SSH feature.