# ssh into WSL2 works on only some IP addresses

Tags: linux, router, ssh, ip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Win10, in WSL 2 running Ubuntu 20, I've installed sshd running on a port different from 22, namely 2222.  To the firewall I've added an incoming rule for TCP port 2222.
From the windows command prompt, `ssh -p 2222 127.0.0.1` works.  So does `ssh -p 2222 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, to the dotted quad reported by WSL's `ifconfig`.

From the windows command prompt (*not* WSL), `ipconfig` reports `192.168.1.yyy`, its address on my router.  Through that address, Windows reaches and is reached by other 192.168.1 hosts on that router (Windows, Mac, Linux; ping, http, mounting disks, ssh *only from* WSL).

From the windows command prompt, `ssh -p 2222 192.168.1.yyy` fails with `Connection refused`.  **How can I make that work?**

- PuTTY 0.74 behaves the same as the windows command prompt's ssh.
- `ssh -v -v -v` adds possibly useful diagnostics:

```
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.yyy] port 2222.
    debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000002E243EDC460
    debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.yyy port 2222: Connection refused
```

- If in sshd_config I restrict ListenAddress to `192.168.1.yyy:2222`, then the other incoming ssh's fail as expected.  So what needs configuring may be not ssh but WSL itself.  `ifconfig -a` doesn't mention any 192.168's.
- Context: this is a stepping stone to enable ssh into WSL from the router's other hosts.  For now WSL's /etc/ssh/sshd_config uses PasswordAuthentication; I'll later change that to PubKeyAuthentication.

Comment: Just a comment, but you may wish to have a look at [this random blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine) for a possible way to solve this. In short, it seems reasonable to assume you may need to forward port `2222` from your Windows host (`192.168.1.yyy`) to the IP of your WSL2 guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer for WSL2 - Use Windows OpenSSH as a jumphost into the WSL instances. You can do this either by ssh'ing to Windows then running the `wsl` command (e.g. `ssh user@windowsip wsl`) or, if you need something more complicated ("real" ssh access), then using SSH on both the Windows host and WSL instance (e.g. `ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p windowshost.local" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2224 localhost`).

For more details, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1622603/1210833).