# How can I directly SSH into the WSL on my Windows 10 machine from another machine (a Mac) on my network?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

The IP of my Windows 10 machine is `192.168.3.108` and the IP of my Mac is `192.168.3.100`.

WSL on my Windows 10 gives this, running SSHD:

```
>wsl hostname -I
172.29.152.15
```

How can I directly SSH into the WSL on my Windows 10 machine without having to connect to the Windows 10 machine first?

with Darius' help, I tried this

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=22 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=22 connectaddress=192.168.3.109
```

My mac still cannot connect the WSL, am I using the right ports? Do I need to change something on Windows firewall?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this [blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine). It describes a process for forwarding SSH to WSL2 in Windows.

Comment: Microsoft has documentation on this --> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan does that work for you? The primary idea is to create a forwarding rule from external port to the WSL IP:Port combination

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH the worker's WSL from the controller node's WSL](https://superuser.com/questions/1622581/ssh-the-workers-wsl-from-the-controller-nodes-wsl) and/or [ssh into WSL2 works on only some IP addresses](https://superuser.com/q/1646999/1210833).  The easiest method is to use the Windows host as the jumphost, but you say you don't want to do that.  In that case, see [here](https://superuser.com/q/1618337/1210833) for more general techniques on WSL2 port forwarding.

Comment: *"Am I using the right ports?"* - Anecdotally, I have never had good luck with port 22. You might want to try setting up every everything for SSH on another port (e.g. 2222).