# connect two Windows 10 PCs with Linux subsystem via SSH

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

I have a two Windows 10 PCs with Linux subsystem running Ubuntu. I'd like to connect from one to another via SSH. Would it even be possible? I've already tried PuTTY and it crashed when I runned it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this question -- [SSH into WSL from another machine on the network](https://superuser.com/questions/1622581/ssh-into-wsl-from-another-machine-on-the-network).  It should have the info you need.  You didn't note whether you are using WSL1, WSL2, or both, but the answer covers both.  Simplest method is to install OpenSSH in *Windows*, then `ssh` into *Windows* and then run the `wsl` command from there to access your shell.  But other, more advanced techniques are also provided.  Let me know if you have additional questions after reading that.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, your question seems focused on `ssh` from *WSL* to *WSL*, but then you also mention that PuTTY crashed (which would be Windows PuTTY to WSL).  If you *are* interested in troubleshooting that, then it should be separated into another question, and you should include additional details like the setting you tried as well as the error message that you received.  Thanks!