# If you run MiniDLNA on Ubuntu Subsystem of Windows should the service run as normal?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dlna, upnp

I'm trying to run MiniDLNA (ReadyMedia) on my Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows 10, and I've setup my conf file and checked the status of the service and it looks like it's running. But when I try to look for it on other uPnP devices it doesn't show up. I'm also running the same setup on my raspberry pi and it's perfectly visible. Does this mean that it's not working because it's a subsystem of windows? Is it necessary that I be running my media server installed on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption that you are running on WSL2 and experiencing the same root issue that I discuss in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833).  If you are using WSL2, what you are seeing (or *not* seeing, really) is completely expected.  It's just due to the way that WSL2 is designed.

Regarding the possible workarounds that I provide in that other answer, I do not know whether MiniDLNA will work under WSL1, but if it will, that will be your ​best​ ​bet.​ ​The `netsh` or `socat` port forwarding options there *may* work, but they would definitely require modification due to the multiple ports and protocols used by DLNA.