# Why are SSH connections being blocked when using internal IPs on windows Linux subsystem?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I setup ubuntu linux subsystem on my windows 11 machine, and configured SSH on it, to allow other devices on my network to connect to it.

It works when I am trying to connect from the same computer:

[image]

However, when I connect from another machine or using my private IP from same computer, I keep getting permission denied error:

[image]

My hosts.allow and hosts.deny are empty. My sshd_config is:

```
AllowUsers *

PasswordAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

How can I enable external connections to my SSH server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH into WSL from another machine on the network](https://superuser.com/questions/1622581/ssh-into-wsl-from-another-machine-on-the-network).  There's also some more detail in [localhost and 127.0.0.1 working but not ip address in wsl windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1618337/1210833).  Let me know if you still have questions after reading those.

Comment: 192.168.0.248 isn’t an external IP address. It’s an intranet IP address it only exists within your local intranet